# Hermitian Operator relation for a particular ket

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

If $X$ is a **Hermitian** operator, and if $X^m|\alpha\rangle = 0$, for a particular ket $|\alpha\rangle$, and $m$, being a **positive integer**, prove that, $X|\alpha\rangle = 0$.

How to show this? I have tried for some time, and have failed.

Comment: Hint: Diagonalize $X$.

Comment: the vector is a $0$-eigenvector for $X^m$, hence it is a $0^{1/m}$-eigenvector for $X$